# passing json request to Flask API

Tags: python, flask

I am new to API. I have a below json request:

```
{
    "Description": {
        "punctuation": "yes",
        "stopwords": "yes",
        "lower-case":"yes",
        "lemetization":"yes"
    }
}
```

I want to pass this json to my below service:

```
@app.route('/user_input', methods=['POST'])
def user_input():

    ##Request table and Json request from user
    user_request = request.get_json()
    user_request_df =pd.DataFrame(user_request)
    return print(df.head())
```

I am using the below command to call the service:

```
res = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/user_input", json={"Description": {"punctuation": "yes","stopwords": "yes","lower-case":"yes","lemetization":"yes"}})
```

After running the this line i am getting `<Response [405]>` error.
Here in the above example I am calling one service from another service. Similarly I want to call multiple service.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Response [405]>
```

Status [405](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) is *Method Not Allowed*, this is caused by fact that you are using `GET` HTTP verb (`requests.get`) whilst also allowing only `POST` requests in Flask using `methods=`

```
@app.route('/user_input', methods=['POST'])
```

Try using `requests.post` instead `requests.get`

Edit: I noticed that you do `return print(df.head())` which is same as `return None` as `print` does always `return` `None`. I am not sure what you want to do exatcly, but if you want to get string representation of `df.head()` then you should probably do `str(df.head())`.

Comment: As suggested I have made the change however now I am getting `"Request 200"` error.